# Can someone help me with this error that im getting?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a crypto command but its giving me an error.I tried doing everything i can't seem to fix it. If anyone fixes it please mention how you fixed it i need to learn how cause i get these errors very frequently.
This is the code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ethprice(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD')
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    price = json_data['USD']
  await ctx.send("Etherium price is: $" + price)
```

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

If anyone can help me i'd appriciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mentions, you are trying to add a float to a string. It’s like doing `"Hello" + 3.9`. Python has no clue what to do with it. What you really want is to cast the float to a string, then add that new string to the other string. Would look like:

```py
print("The price is: " + str(price))
```

This works, but a much more readable and easy way is to use f-strings. They automatically format things for you. It looks like this:

```py
print(f"The price is: {price}")
```

They both do the same thing, but the second one is much easier. Both ways will solve your issue though.